# Will the Unity side-bar eventually have configuration options?

Tags: gnome, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Unity be more customizable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9890/will-unity-be-more-customizable)

I ask because of the common, "websites are 1024px wide" issue: will it be possible to change the behaviour of the side-bar, e.g. to auto-hide, move or resize it?

Comment: We will certainly have [Auto-hide](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/639814) but your other suggestions are less likely.